# Get country name from dataframe column by comparing with a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

How to get country name from dataframe column by comparing with a list of string which contain country names?

For example:

```
list = ["pakistan","united kingdom","uk","usa","united states","uae"]

# create dataframe column name is job_location of employee
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'job_location' : ['birmingham, england, united kingdom','new jersey, united states','gilgit-baltistan, pakistan','uae','united states','pakistan','31-c2, gulberg 3, lahore, pakistan'],
    })
df 
job_location
0   birmingham, england, united kingdom
1   new jersey, united states
2   gilgit-baltistan, pakistan
3   uae
4   united states
5   pakistan
6   31-c2, gulberg 3, lahore, pakistan
```

I need a new column in dataframe name as country which contain country name from job_location column.

Comment: 1. Don't name a list `list`, this conflicts with the python builtin. 2. What is the expected output?

Comment: new_column in df which contain country names only which is present in job_loction column. like  job_location
0   united kingdom
1   united states
2   pakistan
3   uae
4   united states
5   pakistan
6   pakistan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not assuming that the country will always be at the end, here is something that should work:

```
import pandas as pd

country_list = ["pakistan","united kingdom","uk","usa","united states","uae"]

# create dataframe column name is job_location of employee
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'job_location' : ['birmingham, england, united kingdom','new jersey, united states','gilgit-baltistan, pakistan','uae','united states','pakistan','31-c2, gulberg 3, lahore, pakistan'],
    })

matching_countries = []

for key, value in df.items():
    for text in value:
        for country in country_list:
                if country in text:
                    matching_countries.append(country)

df['country'] = matching_countries

print (df)
```

Outputs:

```
                          job_location         country
0  birmingham, england, united kingdom  united kingdom
1            new jersey, united states   united states
2           gilgit-baltistan, pakistan        pakistan
3                                  uae             uae
4                        united states   united states
5                             pakistan        pakistan
6   31-c2, gulberg 3, lahore, pakistan        pakistan
```

Comment: It is inefficient to use such loops in pandas

Answer (score 3):

Using `clist` as the list name, you can craft a regex and use `str.extract`:

```
reg = '(%s)' % '|'.join(clist)
df['country'] = df['job_location'].str.extract(reg)
```

Output:

```
                          job_location         country
0  birmingham, england, united kingdom  united kingdom
1            new jersey, united states   united states
2           gilgit-baltistan, pakistan        pakistan
3                                  uae             uae
4                        united states   united states
5                             pakistan        pakistan
6   31-c2, gulberg 3, lahore, pakistan        pakistan
```

But honestly, if the job_location is always nicely formatted with the country as the end, it's probably easier to split on comma and keep the last field

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change your list name. I have done it using list comprehension..

```
df['country'] = [x.split(",")[-1] for x in df['job_location']]
```

**Output:**

|  | job_location | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | birmingham, england, united kingdom | united kingdom |
| 1 | new jersey, united states | united states |
| 2 | gilgit-baltistan, pakistan | pakistan |
| 3 | uae | uae |
| 4 | united states | united states |
| 5 | pakistan | pakistan |
| 6 | 31-c2, gulberg 3, lahore, pakistan | pakistan |